# Deploying local Docker image (DockerFIle) as local Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I started Kubernetes master and minion on local machine using Vagrant. I can create a json file for my Kubernetes pod where I can start several public containers.

However, one Docker container is local one, ontop on `java:8-jdk`, configured with DockerFile.

How can I reference this local Docker container in the kubernetes json pod so Kubernetes can run it?

In other words, does Kubernetes support docker build ;)

Answer (score 4):

After you build the docker image, you can "side-load" it into your locally available images by running `docker load -i /path/to/image.tar`. Once you've done this, Kubernetes will be able to load the image without reaching out to an external hub.

Comment: nice! how do i specify the name of such image in Kubernetes json? Just as a path as well?

Comment: When you build the image, you can tag it as if you were going to upload it to a hub (e.g. docker hub or gcr.io or quay.io) but just don't push it. Then you can reference it as if you pushed it and docker will be able to find it.